# Camel Splitter Unit Test get wrong ExpectedMessageCount

Tags: spring, unit-testing, apache-camel

I have to write unit test for a camel RouteBuilder that use splitter pattern.

**Here my RouteConfiguration**

```
protected void configureTest(){
    from("direct:in").id("in")
            .to("mock:a")
            .split(body())
                .to("mock:b")
            .end();
}
```

**And the test**

```
public class AlertingRouteBuilderTest extends CamelSpringTestSupport {
    @Test
    public void testest() throws Exception {

        String[] bodyArray = new String[]{"tenant1", "tenant2", "tenant3"};
        getMockEndpoint("mock:a").setExpectedMessageCount(1);
        getMockEndpoint("mock:b").setExpectedMessageCount(3);
        template.sendBody("direct:in", bodyArray);
        assertNotNull(context.hasEndpoint("direct:in"));
        assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();
    }
}

@Override
protected AbstractApplicationContext createApplicationContext() {
    return new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:cmCtx_alertingProcessTest.xml");
}
```

with this context.xml file

```
<bean id="A"
      class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock">
      <constructor-arg value="foo.AProcessor"/>
</bean>

<bean id="B"
      class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock">
    <constructor-arg value="foo.BProcessor"/>
</bean>

<bean id="routeBuilder" 
    class="foo.RouteBuilder" >
</bean>

<camel:camelContext  id="context-objectAnalysis"   trace="true" errorHandlerRef="errorHandler">
    <camel:propertyPlaceholder id="properties" location="camel.properties"/>
    <camel:routeBuilder  ref="routeBuilder"/>
</camel:camelContext>
```

I tried different way to split my body

```
.split(body())
.split(body(String[].class))
....
```

But I get

```
java.lang.AssertionError: mock://b Received message count. Expected: <3> but was: <0>
```

I don't understand why my splitter does'nt go into my mock:b processor.
In the trace console I have

```
16:18:34.046 [main] DEBUG o.a.camel.processor.SendProcessor - >>>> Endpoint[mock://a] Exchange[Message: [Ljava.lang.String;@58ec5e8]
16:18:34.051 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.component.mock.MockEndpoint - mock://a >>>> 0 : Exchange[Message: [Ljava.lang.String;@58ec5e8] with body: [Ljava.lang.String;@58ec5e8 and headers:{breadcrumbId=ID-EFR02223-61984-1495635511863-0-1}
16:18:34.053 [main] INFO  o.a.c.processor.interceptor.Tracer - ID-EFR02223-61984-1495635511863-0-2 >>> (direct:in) mock://a --> split[bodyAs[[Ljava.lang.String;]] <<< Pattern:InOnly, Headers:{breadcrumbId=ID-EFR02223-61984-1495635511863-0-1}, BodyType:String[], Body:[Ljava.lang.String;@58ec5e8
16:18:34.064 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.processor.MulticastProcessor - Done sequential processing 3 exchanges
```

Tell me if you need more info to help me.

**EDIT:**

camel version 2.12.1

Thanks.

Comment: How did you configure/implement the context (`createApplicationContext` of CamelSpringTestSupport)? I tried with the simple `CamelTestSupport` and the snippets you've provided and the test was successful.

Comment: What camel version was used for that?

Comment: see edit of **TEST** and new "with this .xml file" code block

Comment: I tested it with simple CamelTestSupport and it work too.
Any idea why it's not working with CamelSpringTestSupport ?